# jQuery success, access HTTP status text

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I access the original HTTP status text coming back from the server in case that a post call was successfull. For an error there is the option errorThrown in the `.error` method. Is there an analog parameter in `.success`?

Code:

```
  $.post(UI.SelectionList.settings.leftReturnURL, {
      delegateId: $(this).data('id')
  }, function (data, text, xhr) {}).success(function() {
      console.log(arguments);
  });
```

Console output:

```
["", "success", Object] //Object is the jqXHR object, statusText inside is also "success"
```

Comment: The jQXHR object contains a status field

Comment: if ever unsure you can see the arguments by doing a `console.log(arguments);` inside your function

Answer (score 6):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/",

    success: function(data, textStatus, jQXHR) {
        console.log(jQXHR.status, jQXHR.statusText);
        //200 "OK"
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm using the $.post method and the jqXHR.statusText always is "success" not the original http status text

Comment: I've tested your code, you're wrong! jQXHR.statusText is 200 "success"

Comment: @pbcoder can't reproduce that, see http://jsfiddle.net/UdwxN/2/ it is `"OK"` for me always.

Comment: Getting the same result on jsfiddle.net but I can't unterstand why it is overwritten in my case.

Comment: @pbcoder copy your success code exactly as it is in your page.. you probably are doing something differently

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/ZJqxm/. You are using the second parameter, not the third one which is an object and has the proper properties.

Comment: Still shows ´success´ on my site, on jsfiddle everything is working fine

Comment: It is working fine if I'm calling '/' as URL and displays the error message.

Comment: @pbcoder I don't understand, if there is an error then success won't be called

Comment: The solution to the problem was to use the latest version of jQuery. You can reproduce the error by using jQuery 1.5.2 in jsfiddle.net.